# Filter object in JSON

Tags: javascript

Hi I have an object in json, a key-value structure :

```
alpha = {0:12, 1:123, 2:50, 3:50 }
```

I would like to create a new dictionary only with values of alpha equals to 50. I need this :

```
beta = {2:50, 3:50}
```

How can I filter my alpha object ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Object.fromEntries, filter and Object.entries

```js
const data = {0: 12, 1: 123, 2: 50, 3: 50}

const final = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).filter(([_, v]) => v === 50))

console.log(final)
```

---

Or a simple `for..in` loop

```js
const data = { 0: 12, 1: 123, 2: 50, 3: 50}
let final = {}

for (let key in data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(key) && data[key] === 50) {
    final[key] = 50
  }
}

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably this can help:

```js
const alpha = {
  0: 12,
  1: 123,
  2: 50,
  3: 50
}
const beta = {}
Object.entries(alpha).forEach(element => {
  if (element[1] === 50)
    beta[element[0]] = element[1]
})
console.log(beta)
```

Here is the output: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-shtern-dshwz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you can display the output here on SO by going to the editor and then clicking on the code symbol.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = {
  0: 12,
  1: 123,
  2: 50,
  3: 50
}

const beta = {}; 
  Object.values(data).forEach((value,index) => value === 50 ? beta[index] = value : '');

console.log(beta)
```